# Run Windows Forms Application With Visual Basic on Linux

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, mono, visual-studio-code

I am creating Windows Forms application using Visual Basic. And I recently wanted to debug my apps on Linux environment. Recently, Microsoft launches its [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com), I tried it. But It depends on Mono project to debug VB.NET application. And mono-project don't seem to support this kind of application. I am now looking for alternative ways to debug/launch my applications in a Linux environment.

Comment: You can't. You need to separate the application logic from the visual forms layout into separate libraries, and then use gtk+ for the visual forms layer on linux.

Comment: Thanks for the dropping me a comment. I have multi-thread windows form applications And I use this [kind of list](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView)   To show the Status of threads that are working, every thread has its own row on the List, And I want to know how can I use gtk+ in the visual forms layer.